# Where is 'Pipeline: Model definition' on Jenkins 2.89.3

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am getting this 'No such DSL method 'pipeline' found among steps' from Jenkins. From a quick google search, it seems like I am missing the Pipeline: Model definition plugin. However, I can't find the plugin on in 'Plugin Manager'. I have tried to install 'Pipeline: Model API', and a few other plugins with no luck resolving the issue.

How can i install 'Pipeline: Model definition' on jenkins 2.89.3?

Comment: Installing 'Pipeline: Model definition' resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Installing 'Pipeline: Model definition' resolve the issue

Comment: This seems not like an answer to your question, how you actually install this.